# Is it possible to use UNION here instead of OR?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

UPDATE: Changed title. Previous title "Does UNION instead of OR always speed up queries?"

Here is my query. The question is concerning the second last line with the OR:

```
SELECT distinct bigUnionQuery.customer
FROM ((SELECT buyer.customer
       FROM membership_vw buyer
       JOIN account_vw account
       ON account.buyer = buyer.id
       WHERE account.closedate >= 'some_date')
       UNION
       (SELECT joint.customer
       FROM entity_vw joint
       JOIN transactorassociation_vw assoc
       ON assoc.associatedentity = joint.id
       JOIN account_vw account
       ON account.buyer = assoc.entity
       WHERE assoc.account is null and account.closedate >= 'some_date')
       UNION
       (SELECT joint.customer
       FROM entity_vw joint
       JOIN transactorassociation_vw assoc
       ON assoc.associatedentity = joint.id
       JOIN account_vw account
       ON account.id = assoc.account
       WHERE account.closedate >= '2021-02-11 00:30:22.339')) 
AS bigUnionQuery
JOIN entity_vw
ON entity_vw.customer = bigUnionQuery.customer OR entity_vw.id = bigUnionQuery.customer
WHERE entity_vw.lastmodifieddate >= 'some_date';
```

The original query doesn't have the OR in the second last line. Adding the OR here has slowed down the query. I'm wondering if there is a way to use UNION here to speed it up.

I tried doing (pseudo):

```
bigUnionQuery bq join entity_vw e on e.customer = bq.customer
union
bigUnionQuery bq join entity_vw e on e.id = bq.customer
```

But that slowed down the query even more, probably because the bigUnionQuery is a large, slow query, and running it twice in the UNION is not the correct way. What would be the right way to use UNION here, or is it always going to be faster with OR?

Comment: I don't understand what you are really asking.   Are you really asking just about `union` versus `or`?  Or are you looking for ideas on how to speed up your query?

Comment: We don't even know what makes your query slow. Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries to the question.

Comment: If there is no possibility of records meeting both criteria, you may get some speed improvement by using `UNION ALL` (without the `ALL` the database will be forced to check for and remove duplicates). You may also want to consider that change in your `UNION`s in the "bigUnionQuery".

Answer (score 1):

Does UNION instead of OR always speed up queries? In some cases it does. I think it depends on your indexes too. I have worked on tables with 1 million records and my queries' speed usually improves if I use union instead of 'or' or 'and'.